# Preprocessor directives and unnecessary Using directives

Tags: c#, preprocessor-directive, using-directives

I have some code that i need only to be run in a deployed environment (stage/test/production).

The code genereates some usings to other namespaces that appear at the top of the `.cs` file.

However, when i put this code inside my preprocessor directive `#IF !DEBUG` the usings at the top of the `.cs` file now claims

> Using directive is unnecessary.

This feels dangerous. Since this is a multiple personnell project, i fear that someone is going to enter this file at some point and just auto-remove the usings since they're flagged as unnecessary.

My current solution is to just comment the code at the top of the file to not remove them.

So, how can i make my unnecessary usings directives non-unnecessary?

Comment: Are you using directives also in a #IF !DEBUG

Comment: Are you using directives also in a #IF !DEBUG

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft no, is that a thing? I was not aware that was a thing.

Comment: I haven't tested, but it should be a thing. Does it work?

Comment: Either fully qualify the types used in the ifdef section, or place the using directives inside #ifdef's as well.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes, fully qualifying the types solves the problem. I'll probably use that.

Comment: It is, however, usually better to handle things like this using feature flags or environment flags. Injecting services, etc.

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft It is a thing and it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your usings a #IF too:

```
#IF !DEBUG
using MySpecialStuff 
#endif

public class MyClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
#IF !DEBUG
        var msc = new MySpecialClass(); 
#endif
    }   
}
```

Or, fully qualify the class you need in the declaration.

```
public class MyClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
#IF !DEBUG
        var msc = new MySpecialStuff.MySpecialClass(); 
#endif
    }   
}
```